# If sequence $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ decrease to $0$, and $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} a_nb_n$ converges, then $b_n\sum_{l=1}^n a_l \to 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If sequence $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ decrease to $0$, and $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} a_nb_n$ converges, then how to prove
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_1+a_2+\cdots a_n)b_n =0.
\end{equation}
I think I need to use Abel's summation $\sum_{n=1}^p a_nb_n = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (b_k - b_{k+1}) (\sum_{l=1}^{k} a_l)+b_p\sum_{l=1}^p a_l$, but I do not know how to use it, could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

This is [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma), stated differently:

> For a convergent series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n$, and $0<\beta_1\leqslant\beta_2\leqslant\ldots$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\beta_n=\infty$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\beta_n}\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k\beta_k=0.$$

(Just put $\alpha_n=a_n b_n$ and $\beta_n=1/b_n$.)